# ui:repeat in datatable export as XLS (Primefaces)

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to export my datatable to Excel by using the following code:

```
<p:dataTable id="potentialDonorFileTable" var="potentialDonorFile"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {Exporters}"
                     value="#{analyseBackingBean.allPotentialDonorFiles}" rows="30"
                     paginator="true" lazy="true">

            <f:facet name="{Exporters}">
                <h:commandLink>
                    <h:outputText id="downloadAsXls" value="download"/>
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="potentialDonorFileTable" fileName="potontial-donor-files"/>
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['registration.number']}">
                <h:outputText value="#{potentialDonorFile.registrationNumber}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

and this is working correctly. However, now I need to display a list of items in a certain column and also export that list to excel.

```
            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['reason']}">
                <ui:repeat value="#{potentialDonorFile.list}"
                           var="item">
                    <h:outputText
                            value="#{msgs['enum.translation.'.concat(item)]}"/>
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:column>
```

The values are correctly displayed, but when I'm exporting this datatable to excel then I'm getting the following cell: "com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@6063d832". Is there any way to work around this using primefaces 5.2?

Comment: Only option is to enhance the exporter so it also supports the `ui:repeat`. It currently does not, or to do all the concatting server side in a method in a bean

Comment: can you replace repeat with c:forEach and try?

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar this can't be done because a c:forEach is evaluated before the datatable. So my "potenialDonorFile" won't be known yet.

Comment: Fixed it by creating a backingBean method which does the translation and returns a String representation of the list -> (translatedItem1, translatedItem2, ..)

Comment: how did you do the translation from string "com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@6063d832" to so manageable object where you can get the values?